# Preview Xamarin Form Pages

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, preview, designer

Is there any way to preview a Xamarin forms page without first deploying to device/emulator?

Or is there any way to live edit the page and see changes somewhere (a bit like Snoopy for WPF).
I tried both Xamarin Studio + Visual Studio and do not see a designer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 30 Sept 2016:**

Using the latest version of Xamarin you can use the following steps:

Use the **View** > **Other Windows** > **Xamarin.Forms Previewer** menu in Visual Studio to open the preview window. Use the **Window** > **New Vertical Tab Group menu** to position it side-by-side like the image below:

[image]

Note that:

> The previewer requires that the project be built before rendering a
>   page. If the error 'Invalid XAML' appears at the top of the preview pane,
>   re-build the application and try again.

[Source](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/)

**Old Answer for reference to other solutions:**

The Xamarin.Forms Previewer is currently only available in Xamarin Studio in the Alpha channel. [Follow these instructions to change the update channel](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/).

Currently there is no **official** Xamarin Forms UI previewer for visual studio. However in the last Xamarin Evolve 2016, Xamarin announced that they are working on a designer that will be released. It is to be [announced](https://xamarinhelp.com/visual-designer-xamarin-forms/).

> Xamarin recently released a Xamarin Previewer, for Xamarin Studio only
>   (Visual Studio to come later) that lets you preview XAML on iOS and
>   Android. This is currently in preview and available via the Alpha
>   channel (29th April 2016). I will try to remember to update this once
>   it comes out for Visual Studio.

As an unofficial alternatives, you can try:

[Gorilla Player](http://gorillaplayer.com/)

Comment: Thanks :-( Guess I will have to live with the 10-15second delay each time

Comment: @MichalCiechan or switch to Xamarin Studio. Or pay for Gorilla player :)

Comment: @user3185569 thanks.. But already upvoted.. only one upvote allowed per user:)

Comment: Thanks for the update! in the end I went with Gorilla Player, but now that it's officially out (and hopefully I will be able to access it this time) I will give the previewer a spin :-)

Comment: I can open the previewer in VS, but it's not showing a render of the page if I then open a xaml file.  Is there something you need to do to tell the Previewer what to actually preview?

Comment: Answering my own questions, it looks like there are still a lot of issues with running the previewer in VS, particularly that you need the mac agent running on a connected mac even if you only want to preview Android layots.  More info on the Xamarin forums: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/78018/xamarin-forms-previewer-isnt-showing/p2

Comment: Note that in Visual Studio 2017 the entry below "Other windows" is just called "Forms Previewer" (without `Xamarin.`).

Answer (score 6):

Xamarin.Forms Previewer is now available in VS. All you need to do is to update your Xamarin version: **Tools** > **Options** > **Xamarin** > **Other** > **Check Now** to update your Xamarin to the latest.

Then open it via **View** > **Other Windows** > **Xamarin.Forms Previewer**

UPDATE: But it looks like that it does not show anything from my XAML!

Comment: While previewing your XAML file you must be connected to your mac agent.

Answer (score 4):

Xamarin Studio does include a XAML previewer, I've been using it for awhile now.

[image]

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I'm looking for! Just switched to Alpha channel :-) Now if only my internet was faster :-(

Comment: @MichalCiechan No problem, It is not "perfect" yet as it does not recover  from XML syntax errors all the time so you might have to close and reopen the XAML file to get it to recompile the XAML to code as it is actually live running the code..

Comment: I installed the latest Alpha channel version (6.1) and it still is not giving me any XAML Preview button in top right :-( Gonna try out Gorilla Player

Answer (score 1):

I left [here](http://devrecipeshb.blogspot.co.il/2016/10/xamarin-forms-real-time-designer.html) my impressions after my own research on the topic, having tried:

1. Xamarin's Previewer
2. Xamarin Forms Player
3. Gorilla Player

**Bottom line**:

I decided to go with Gorilla Player. The only one that really worked with me - although it has the limitation of working with XAML only - meaning you are forced to code your UI using XAML.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin.Forms Previewer is available in the **stable channel** as a Preview.

Projects require the latest Xamarin.Forms NuGet package for the XAML Previewer to work.

Open Android SDK Manager and update SDK Tools and Platform-Tools

[image]

Rebuild solution and create new xaml page.

In Visual Studio:
Use the View > Other Windows > Xamarin.Forms Previewer menu to open the preview window.
Et voilà

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/